# SSDT 2012 - ssis deployment error

Tags: ssis

I am trying to deploy a SSDT 2012 SSIS project using Deploy option. But I am getting below error:

> TITLE: SQL Server Integration Services
>
> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "deploy_project_internal": 
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: A required privilege is not held by the client
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerProcess.StartProcess(Boolean bSuspendThread)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ServerApi.DeployProjectInternal(SqlInt64 deployId, SqlInt64 versionId, SqlInt64 projectId, SqlString projectName)
>   . (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 6522)
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=11.00.5058&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=6522&LinkId=20476

Any idea why this error? below is the screen shot of the error.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I have faced this issue after installation of [Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843). After installation I started repair option of SQL server management studio by running SQL Server Setup. After restarting SQL Server Management studio issue resolved Now I can deploy SSIS package in Integration Service Catalog. [image: Repair Option Shown below]

Answer (score 4):

That error often means the SQL Server Agent account is missing a permission somewhere. The "A required privilege is not held by the client" in this case means the SQL Agent account is called to do something but isn't permitted to.

One thing to try is to use the SQL Server Configuration Manager, as administrator, to reset the account for SQL Server Agent (and possibly SQL Server itself). This will reinstate the required permissions if you have sufficient rights.

I have seen cases where Group Policy prohibited the assignment of the service account to needed permissions at the OS level, which really creates a problem.

Example: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccesstechnologies/archive/2012/08/20/error-while-deploying-ssis-2012-project-from-ssdt-to-ssis-catalog-system-componentmodel-win32exception-a-required-privilege-is-not-held-by-the-client.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Went through most of the other solutions but using the repair option worked.

The problem could have been due to the installation of Visual Studio and SSDT after SQL was installed.

Would be nice if MS provided better support for their products rather than leaving to the community to fix the problem.

Comment: The repair worked for us as well, on a clean SQL 2019 installation. Nothing else had been installed since.

Comment: After fixing the problem with a Repair, the problem is now back (next working day). I'm thinking it's GPO related in our case.

Answer (score 0):

According to this Blog the required User Right may be

"Replace a process level token"

https://www.oraylis.de/blog/fixing-sql-2012-ssis-deployment-error-6522-a-required-privilege-is-not-held-by-the-client